Ошибка при помещение дроби в переменную MASM
Пусть у меня есть код:
.data
    double real8 ?
.code
main proc
    mov double, 2.5 ; Ошибка 
main endp
end

При помещении в дробную переменную дробь и компиляции с помощью MASM появляется ошибка.
Текст ошибки:  error A2050:real or BCD number not allowed.
Как избавиться от этой ошибки?

Насколько я понял, так в принципе нельзя. Нужно такие константы в .data описать и оттуда на них ссылаться. Иначе придётся вручную переводить в 16-ричный вид и в таком виде везде писать.

CrazyElf, а как переводить в шестнадцатеричный вид?

Не знаю. Попробуйте вписать прямо в своё определение .data double real8 2.5 и посмотрите, во что оно скомпилируется.

CrazyElf, спасибо.
